# Rendering objects which are not visible?

Tags: 3d, game-engine

You know that in 3d games, there are many objetcs. my question is does GPU render the objects which are not visible? i.e. those parts of the world gaming which is for instance behind the camera...tnx

Answer (score 0):

No, on a proper engine that information would not get passed to the GPU during that frame, same goes for non-visible objects. Sending them to the GPU would just slow down the framerate (most games bottleneck at the GPU) so calculations are done beforehand to make sure something will actually be on screen, before asking them to be rendered. If this isn't the case, the graphics card will still render things off screen and this can cause low framerates in a lot of cases. Like I said earlier though, most graphics and/or games engines will already account for this properly.